# search string format in current or next line until match

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, icalendar

ics file generated by [evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:-//Ximian//NONSGML Evolution Calendar//EN
VERSION:2.0
X-EVOLUTION-DATA-REVISION:2017-10-28T04:50:31.240215Z(0)
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/Asia/Kolkata
X-LIC-LOCATION:Asia/Kolkata
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:IST
DTSTART:19701014T230000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VTODO
UID:f13168013f7c8b9abc36c31e43028c34a3f40823
DTSTAMP:20171019T025556Z
SUMMARY:Trial
DTSTART;TZID=/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/Asia/Kolkata:
 20171019T000000
DUE;TZID=/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/Asia/Kolkata:20171030T000000
PERCENT-COMPLETE:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Hello
SEQUENCE:2
CREATED:20171019T031330Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20171028T045031Z
CATEGORIES:Work
END:VTODO
END:VCALENDAR
```

The problem is in the line 20-23 where:

```
DTSTART;TZID=/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/Asia/Kolkata:
 20171019T000000
DUE;TZID=/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/Asia/Kolkata:20171030T000000
```

So, the DTSTART's time is in the next line while the DUE's timestamp is in the same line. Hence, a simple python function like:

```
   if line.startswith("DTSTART;TZID"):
      line = next(finp)
      dt = line.strip()[0:8]
```

wont work for both. This one won't works for DUE, and I have to make another function without `next` for that purpose.

How can I handle any such date/time etc irrespective of the linebreak?

Comment: I am not sure why negative voting is given, but its irritating when people do manage time to put negative voting but don't care to answer or tell why its a bad question.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe using regex would be useful in your case,
try this:

```
 import re
 if line.startswith("DTSTART;TZID"):
     line = next(finp)
     dt = re.search('(.*)T.*', line).groups(1)

 if line.startswith("DTSTART;TZID"):
     dt = re.search('.*\:(.*)T.*', line).groups(1)
```

The first group that's wrapped in () is in both cases the datestamp.

To decipher the regex; .* matches anything until the explictly named character occurs, which is in the first scenario 'T' because of the newline and the "plain" string given to us. In the second the stamp is between ':' and 'T' which enclose the date.

Using String-Slicing could become difficult when you are not sure if the city is always Kolkata etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but please realise that you have just shown what I have already did. I am not asking for regex, but if there is anyway to avoid 'next' in DTSTART.